# Storing the id attribute of all elements using CssSelector in a list using Selenium

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

The Python selenium code I have here takes us to a page with some datasets I'm interested in scraping. Here's my code.

```
import time, os
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences= {"download.default_directory": os.getcwd(), "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
#options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

url = "http://www.ssp.sp.gov.br/transparenciassp/"

# Path of my WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


# to maximize the browser window
driver.maximize_window()

#get method to launch the URL
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cphBody_btnHomicicio"))).click()

for x in range(18, 19):
    year = '#cphBody_lkAno'+str(x)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, year))).click()
    
    for x in range(1, 2):
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cphBody_lkMes'+str(x)))).click()
```

So far this works, but my issue comes with the last loop of this syntax, even though it does exactly what I want. What I want to do, is select all of the elements on the page with a CSS selector which contain the text "cphBody_lkMes" and put them in a list like

```
['#cphBody_lkMes1','#cphBody_lkMes2', ...]
```

so that I can loop through them accordingly. The current code appears messy.

When I try

```
for x in range(18, 19):
    year = '#cphBody_lkAno'+str(x)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, year))).click()
    
    meses = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("//*[contains(text(),'cphBody_lkMes')]")
    
    meses
    
    for x in range(1, 2):
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cphBody_lkMes'+str(x)))).click()
```

the list comes up as empty, and an error says

```
An invalid or illegal selector was specified.
```

How might I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all of the elements on the page with a CSS selector whose `id` attribute starts with *`cphBody_lkMes`* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("id") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.nav.nav-pills.mesNav li > a[id^='cphBody_lkMes']")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("id") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='nav nav-pills mesNav']//li/a[starts-with(@id, 'cphBody_lkMes')]")))])
  ```

---

### Update

To iterate the list:

```
months = [my_elem.get_attribute("id") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.nav.nav-pills.mesNav li > a[id^='cphBody_lkMes']")))]
for month in months:
    print(month)
```

Comment: Okay so I see the list, but how would I store this list as something I can loop over? That is, if I wanted to name it "meses" or "months" for example, how would I do that in this context? @undetected Selenium

Comment: @JaredGreathouse Eventually I did the same :) my initial list was created as `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='nav nav-pills mesNav']//li/a[starts-with(@id, 'cphBody_lkMes')]")))` then I used **List Comprehension** to create the second list containing the `ID` attributes. Now you whatsoever way use the value of the `ID` attributes.

Comment: @JaredGreathouse Checkout the updated answer and let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Okay so that works, now I suppose the last piece of the puzzle is how to click on it. When I do ```wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, month))).click()```,  I get a timeout exception, implying that Selenium isn't recognizing the element of the list. EDIT: I solved it, I did '#'+month and it worked fine. Thank you all so much.

Comment: @JaredGreathouse Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues here:

1. You are defining `x` index both in outer and the inner `for` loops
2. It should be `meses = driver.find_elements_by_xpath` there instead of `meses = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector`
3. And finally `cphBody_lkMes` are the substrings of elements `id` values, not the `text` values.
   So, this gives me non-empty `meses` list:

```py
for x in range(18, 19):
    year = '#cphBody_lkAno' + str(x)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, year))).click()
    meses = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'cphBody_lkMes')]")

    for y in range(1, 2):
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cphBody_lkMes' + str(y)))).click()
```