# Pull data from a div class Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to pull a specific number out of a div class in Python Selenium but can't figure out how to do it. I'd want to get the "post_parent" ID `947630` as long as it matches the "post_name" number starting `09007`.

I'm looking to do this across multiple "post_name" classes, so I'd feed it something like this: `search_text = "0900766b80090cb6"`, but there will be multiple in the future so it has to read the "post_name" first then pull the "post_parent" if that makes sense.

Appreciate any advice anyone has to offer.

```
    <div class="hidden" id="inline_947631">
    <div class="post_title">Interface Converter</div>
    <div class="post_name">0900766b80090cb6</div>
    <div class="post_author">28</div>
    <div class="comment_status">closed</div>
    <div class="ping_status">closed</div>
    <div class="_status">inherit</div>
    <div class="jj">06</div>
    <div class="mm">07</div>
    <div class="aa">2001</div>
    <div class="hh">15</div>
    <div class="mn">44</div>
    <div class="ss">17</div>
    <div class="post_password"></div>
    <div class="post_parent">947630</div>
    <div class="page_template">default</div>
    <div class="tags_input" id="rs-language-code_947631">de</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see `<div class="post_name">0900766b80090cb6</div>` this and `<div class="post_parent">947630</div>` are siblings nodes to each other.

You can use `xpath -> following-sibling` like this:

**Code:**

```
search_text = "0900766b80090cb6"
post_parent_num = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='post_name' and text()='{search_text}']//following-sibling::div[@class='post_parent']").text
print(post_parent_num)
```

**or Using ExplicitWait:**

```
search_text = "0900766b80090cb6"
post_parent_num = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='post_name' and text()='{search_text}']//following-sibling::div[@class='post_parent']"))).get_attribute('innerText')
print(post_parent_num)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update:**

```
NoSuchElementException:
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML-DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//div[@class='post_name' and text()='0900766b80090cb6']//following-sibling::div[@class='post_parent']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If this is unique `//div[@class='post_name' and text()='0900766b80090cb6']//following-sibling::div[@class='post_parent']` then you need to check for the below conditions as well.

1. Check if it's in any `iframe/frame/frameset`.

   **Solution:** switch to iframe/frame/frameset first and then interact with this web element.
2. Check if it's in any `shadow-root`.

   **Solution:** Use `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector` to have returned a web element and then operates accordingly.
3. Make sure that the element is rendered properly before interacting with it. Put some `hardcoded delay` or `Explicit wait` and try again.

   **Solution:** `time.sleep(5)` or

   `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='post_name' and text()='0900766b80090cb6']//following-sibling::div[@class='post_parent']"))).text`
4. If you have redirected to a `new tab/ or new windows` and you have not **switched** to that particular `new tab/new window`, otherwise you will likely get `NoSuchElement` exception.

   **Solution:** switch to the relevant window/tab first.
5. If you have switched to an iframe and the new desired element is not in the same iframe context then first `switch to default content` and then interact with it.

   **Solution:** switch to default content and then switch to respective iframe.

Comment: Hey @cruisepandey, thanks for the response. I have tried running this through my script, however it doesn't print out at the end. I am receiving no errors either which is strange, any thoughts?

Comment: may be some time delay issue, could you run the code that I have given under `ExplicitWait` or else first code with some `time.sleep(5)`

Comment: I have ran that now and an error has appeared, however it's not very descriptive it just says : 'TimeoutException: Message:'. I'm thinking maybe that class is hidden?

Comment: Yes could be, you will get the exact error if you run the first code and put `time.sleep(5)` before the `driver.find_element` command.

Comment: so I've jiggled it around a bit and I'm getting the 'NoSuchElementException' error now, so it seems it may be hidden. I'm hopeful that there's a way to unhide it, do you know of any resources I can look at?

Comment: to solve `NoSuchElementException`, I'd encourage you to check the Update section above. You should debug point by point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any specific relation between "post_parent" ID `947630` and "post_name" number starting `09007`. Moreover, the parent `<div>` is having *`class="hidden"`*.

However, to pull the specific number you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='inline'] div.post_parent").text)
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id, 'inline_')]//div[@class='post_parent']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='inline'] div.post_parent"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id, 'inline_')]//div[@class='post_parent']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Are you sure you can use starts-with ?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Of coarse yes, check the xpath in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71640586/7429447)

Comment: Sorry I don't see the relevant info in that discussion. I thought that natively Selenium uses the XPATH of the browser and that is by default 1.0 without starts-with(). Se i.e. https://quick-adviser.com/what-version-of-xpath-does-selenium-use/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method and use the following `xpath` to get the `post_parent` text based on `post_name` text.

```
def getPostPatent(postname):
    element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='post_name' and starts-with(text(),'{}')]/following-sibling::div[@class='post_parent']".format(postname))
    print(element.get_attribute("textContent"))

getPostPatent('09007')
```

This will return value if it is matches the text `starts-with('09007')`

It seems parent class is hidden you need to use `textContent` to get the value.

Comment: Are you sure you can use starts-with ?